# Do these words need an article?

Tags: grammar

Are these sentences correct according to my reasoning?

- (The) *x* axis represents time.
- (The) *b* variable is the length.

Since *x* and *b* are specific nouns, so we drop the articles.

- The subject is in (a) resting condition.

"Condition" is a noncountable noun here so it doesn't need an article.

- In **a** task-based protocol, **the** experiment is repeated over many trials.

Both "task-based protocol" and "experiment" are general nouns in a definition. But "experiment" is also specific in that it refers to the "experiment" in a "task-based protocol" so we should use "a" for "task-based protocol" and "the" for the "experiment".

Comment: I am afraid you have not given enough information in your question.  What kind of document are you talking about?  It makes all the difference whether it is a formal essay or, for example, user instructions.  Is your first language English? If not, is it a language (like Russian) which in many cases does not use an article which in English would always be used?

Comment: Also, you might or might not need an article depending on the use in the sentence. "In *my* task-based protocol, *important* experiments are repeated..." Note that you didn't use one yourself before "trials." Please edit your question to tell us more about the context you're asking about!

Comment: Articles are not determined by the noun phrase they're in, but by that noun phrase's meaning and use in a sentence. Without sentence examples, there's not enough information; it's like a list of PDFs with no boundary conditions.

Comment: @Tuffy It is for my thesis which of course should be formal. I'm not a native speaker and I don't understand how my own language might affect the correctness of my writing in English.

Comment: I rewrote the question to be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While *x* in "*x* axis" might be a noun, if it is then it's an attributive noun which functions as an adjective.

Consider a question and answer like

> Which frame is largest?
> The door frame is largest.

The main noun in your sentence is **axis,** and that does need an article, just like *frame* does in my example.

The same applies to your sentence about the variable, but we wouldn't generally phrase it as "The *b* variable": it would be "The variable *b* is the length". Here, *b* is a **name,** and the sentence is analogous to something like "The man Andrew is the president". That's a slightly defective analogy, but we certainly wouldn't say "The Andrew man is the president".

*Condition* in your third sentence is a **countable** noun. The subject could be in one of any number of conditions, resting or running or anything else. Because it's countable, it needs an article, and the indefinite article is appropriate.

Your reasoning for the last sentence is correct.